# How to interpret multiple interactions in lm

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, regression-coefficients, lm

I'm wondering how to interpret the `summary(lm)` output in the context of multiple interactions. Here's some toy data with 2,000 observations, one dependent variable, two conditions (control + treatment), and some further covariates:

```
set.seed(101)
n <- 2000
dv <- rnorm(n)
condition <- sample(c("control","treat"),n,rep=TRUE)
age <- sample(18:85,n,rep=TRUE)
gender <- sample(c("male","female"),n,rep=TRUE)
education <- sample(c("less_than_undergrad","undergrad","post_grad"),n,rep=TRUE)

df <- cbind.data.frame(dv,
                       condition,
                       age,
                       gender,
                       education)
```

Say we think that the treatment effect on `dv` will be different for different levels of `education`. So we fit the following:

```
summary(lm(dv ~ condition +
             age +
             gender +
             education +
             condition:education,
           data = df))
    
Call:
lm(formula = dv ~ condition + age + gender + education + condition:education, 
    data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.2715 -0.6805  0.0090  0.6786  3.2264 

Coefficients:
                                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)                        0.0116217  0.0843061   0.138    0.890
conditiontreat                    -0.0661622  0.0775752  -0.853    0.394
age                                0.0003638  0.0011395   0.319    0.750
gendermale                        -0.0417308  0.0448992  -0.929    0.353
educationpost_grad                -0.0516772  0.0769658  -0.671    0.502
educationundergrad                -0.0381631  0.0786148  -0.485    0.627
conditiontreat:educationpost_grad  0.1508896  0.1089535   1.385    0.166
conditiontreat:educationundergrad  0.0192628  0.1106549   0.174    0.862

Residual standard error: 1.002 on 1992 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.00212,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.001386 
F-statistic: 0.6047 on 7 and 1992 DF,  p-value: 0.7525
```

Here, I believe we would say that, for someone with no undergraduate degree (the reference category), being treated is associated with a decrease in `dv` of 0.0662, holding the other covariates constant. For someone with a postgraduate degree, as opposed to no undergraduate degree, being treated is associated with an increase in `dv` of 0.0847 (-0.0662 + 0.1509), holding the other covariates constant.

But what happens when we include another interaction? Let's say we think that the treatment also interacts with `age`:

```
summary(lm(dv ~ condition +
             age +
             gender +
             education +
             condition:education +
             condition:age,
           data = df))

Call:
lm(formula = dv ~ condition + age + gender + education + condition:education + 
    condition:age, data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.2345 -0.6733  0.0034  0.6782  3.2327 

Coefficients:
                                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)                        0.096527   0.103572   0.932   0.3515  
conditiontreat                    -0.232409   0.141088  -1.647   0.0997 .
age                               -0.001272   0.001625  -0.782   0.4342  
gendermale                        -0.042656   0.044893  -0.950   0.3421  
educationpost_grad                -0.052710   0.076950  -0.685   0.4934  
educationundergrad                -0.036852   0.078601  -0.469   0.6392  
conditiontreat:educationpost_grad  0.150504   0.108927   1.382   0.1672  
conditiontreat:educationundergrad  0.019220   0.110627   0.174   0.8621  
conditiontreat:age                 0.003212   0.002277   1.411   0.1585  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.001 on 1991 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.003117,  Adjusted R-squared:  -0.000889 
F-statistic: 0.7781 on 8 and 1991 DF,  p-value: 0.6221
```

Here's how I *think* we should interpret this: For someone with no undergraduate degree, being treated is associated with a decrease of 0.2324 in `dv` plus an increase of 0.0032 for every year. So, for someone who is 30 years old, the effect would be -0.2324 + 0.0032 * 30 = -0.1364. Having an undergraduate degree as opposed to no undergraduate degree, by contrast, would be associated with an effect of -0.2324 + 0.0192 = -0.2132, plus 0.0032 for every year. So, for a 30-year-old, the effect would be -0.1172.

Am I interpreting that correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Original Model**

The *linear regression model* you fitted to your data looks like this:

$dv = \beta_0 + \beta_1conditiontreat +  \beta_2age + \beta_3gendermale +  \beta_4educationpostgrad +  \beta_5educationundergrad +  \beta_6conditiontreat:educationpostgrad + 
 \beta_7conditiontreat:educationundergrad + \beta_8conditiontreat:age + \epsilon$.

The effect of condition in this model can be determined by re-arranging the model so that it takes the form $dv = intercept + slope * conditiontreat + \epsilon$, in which case the effect of $condition$ will be captured by the $slope$.

**Re-Arranged Model**

The re-arranged model is given by:

$dv = (\beta_0 +  \beta_2age +  \beta_3gendermale + \beta_4educationpostgrad +  \beta_5educationundergrad) +  (\beta_1 + \beta_6 educationpostgrad +  
 \beta_7educationundergrad +  \beta_8 age)conditiontreat  
  + \epsilon$.

In the re-arranged model, the $intercept$ gathers together all terms in the original model which DO NOT depend on the dummy variable $conditiontreat$, while the $slope$ gathers together all terms which DEPEND on $conditiontreat$. This dummy variable is used to capture the effect of $condition$ on the dependent variable $dv$.

**Effects of condition**

From the re-arranged model, it is clear that the effect of $condition$ on $dv$ depends on both education status and age.

For those with no undergraduate degree, the effect of $condition$ is given by $\beta_1 + \beta_8age$.  This effect represents the difference among the mean value of $dv$ between treated and untreated subjects in the target population having the same gender and no undergraduate degree. You can evaluate the effect of 3 different values of age, such as mean(age) - sd(age), mean(age), mean (age) + sd(age) if the distribution of age is approximately bell-shaped. Here, mean() and sd() stand for the sample mean and sample standard deviation.

For those with a post-graduate degree, the effect of $condition$ is given by $\beta_1 + \beta_6 + \beta_8age$.  This effect represents the difference among the mean value of $dv$ between treated and untreated subjects in the target population having the same gender and a post-graduate degree. This effect can be evaluated for meaningfully chosen values of age, as per above.

For those with an undergraduate degree, the effect of $condition$ is given by $\beta_1 + \beta_7 + \beta_8age$.  This effect represents the difference among the mean value of $dv$ between treated and untreated subjects in the target population having the same gender and an undergraduate degree. This effect can be evaluated for meaningfully chosen values of age, as per above.

Of course, once you fit your model to the data, you can replace the true values of the parameters with their estimated values in the above.  For example, $beta_1$ is estimated by -0.232409, etc.